# How can I create a check to make sure only one entry in the column can have a specific value based on an id from a different column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a new table in SQL Developer that has a four columns. In one column there is a numerical value called ORG_ID, this ORG_ID can be the same across multiple entries in the table. Another column is called DEFAULT_FLAG, this column only contains a Y or N character denoting if it is the default entry for the table for that ORG_ID.

I am trying to create a CHECK in the DEFAULT_FLAG column that makes sure there is only one entry with a Y for all entries with the same ORG_ID. Here is an example of what it would look like:

```
xxxx|xxxx|ORG_ID|DEFAULT_FLAG
xxxx|xxxx|123456| Y
xxxx|xxxx|123456| N
xxxx|xxxx|987654| Y
xxxx|xxxx|567495| Y
```

In the above table, the second entry for ORG_ID 123456 would need to be rejected if Y was inserted as the DEFAULT_FLAG.

I'm a little new to SQL, so I've done my research of needing to use a constraint and check on the column. I tried writing my own but it did not work, the code is below.

```
default_flag varchar(1)
constraint  one_default Check(ORG_ID AND DEFAULT_FLAG != "Y"),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You are trying to use a check constraint for something it is not designed for.  You have an `org_id`.  You should have an `organizations` table that uses this id as its primary key.

Then, then flag you want to store should be in the `organizations` table.  Voila!  The flag is only stored once.  You don't need to worry about keeping it in synch between different rows.

Comment: How would a flag in the organizations table tell you which of the existing table's rows is the default one for an `org_id`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . The `organizations` table out have only one row per `org_id`.  It would be the primary key.

Comment: Yes, but the existing table has multiple entries per `org_id`. One of them per `org_id` is the default, the others are not. A mere flag in the `organizations` table cannot tell us which of the existing table's rows are the default rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . As I read the question, there is only one default value:  "In the above table, the second entry for ORG_ID 123456 would need to be rejected if Y was inserted as the DEFAULT_FLAG.".

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how storing the flag in the organizations table will help. To elaborate a little on the question, the current table is for a list of warehouses. One organization can have multiple warehouses, but only one warehouse is the default. So are you saying to store the default warehouse in the organization table, rather than keep a flag in the warehouse table for the default warehouse that belongs to an organization?

Comment: @sdj . . . Yes, storing the default warehouse in the organizations table would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index for all `ORG_ID` entries with a 'Y', so each `ORG_ID` can only have one row with a 'Y':

```
create unique index idx on mytable(case when default_flag = 'Y' then org_id end)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because there will be repeated, non-unique, `NULL` entries for all the places that default_flag is not 'Y'.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: I think the requirement is that there is no more than one default row per `org_id`. This is what the index ensures. Have I misread the request?

Comment: What enters into the index for the rows where default_flag is 'N'?

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: Nothing. Nulls don't make it into the index.

Comment: Tested. `NULL`s do go into the index, at least in Postgres, but since it is _not_ the case that `NULL = NULL` they don't violate uniqueness. (They go into the index for sorts.)

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: In Oracle, when all indexed fields are null, then no entry is made in the index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190731/discussion-between-andrew-lazarus-and-thorsten-kettner).

Answer (score 0):

I think a technically-better solution than the one from Thorsten Kettner, but using the same idea, is

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON mytable(org_id)
WHERE default_flag = 'Y';
```

But let me also suggest a table `organization_defaults` with two columns, one the ID for an organization and the other the ID for `mytable` is a better approach, as suggested in comments to the OP.

Comment: Does Oracle support partial indexes? That would be news to me. I know them from PostgreSQL, but I've never seen them in Oracle.

Comment: I don't know. I've stuck with Postgresql, with a brief forced journey to MySQL. Now learning MonetDB [columnar], which doesn't really support indexes except in name, partial or otherwise. You may guess from this list how much my employers were willing to spend on a database.